# Detecting if File.Move will require 'Copy -> Delete' or just alter location in the file system table

Tags: c#, file-io, filesystems

Disclaimer:
I will admit straight away I have a fair amount of ignorance regarding the details on how file systems function.  I have been using NTFS for so long that I can extrapolate what is going on based on behaviors I have witnessed, as well as whatever I have learned from dorking on the internet - however...

I was hoping that there is a way to detect if when moving a file from 'location A' to 'location B', whether the operation will require the equivalent of 'File.Copy -> File.Delete' or if it will not copy the actual file data, but just update the location in the 'master file table' or the like.

For various purposes, I sometimes move large numbers of large files.  I like to report progress in the UI.

I realize that when I call File.Move and move a file from a location on one disk/partition to another, that the function will effectively have to 'copy file data -> delete' between the disks / partitions.  When it encounters this situation, I want to be able to detect that this will happen so I can use code I have authored that will copy the file and give detailed progress reporting as bytes are transferred so I can update progress bars in the UI frequently.

When it is on the same disk/partition, as updating the location in the master file table is so fast, I simply update the progress bar when the file.Move function completes for each file I am batch moving.

Using .NET 4 (C#), is it possible to detect through other means whether calling the File.Move will require an equivalent 'copy -> delete' operation or will simply update a file table and not copy the file data?

**Edit:**

As I note in comments below, possibilities on how I thought this *might* be done would be to detect if a given source file location and destination file location are located on the same physical disk & partition, and if so, would this mean I could accurately anticipate the behavior and decide what functions to call - the built in File.Move function for the 'near instant' update file system table that I believe occurs when moving to same disk/part, or my more detailed 'report progress every 'x' bytes copied' custom file copy code.  File transfer speeds can vary greatly on the machines my programs will run on so I like to be able to report detailed progress / present transfer speed when possible.

Note - The program may be using network UNC paths which can be using different physical disks with the same root path i.e.:  \\somename\shares\workfolder\project may be on a different physical disk then \\somename\shares\workfoldder\otherproject.  So I would need a method for detecting the partition ID or physical disk ID to see if a source and destination folder on on the same disk/partition.

Thank you

Comment: you have a reason to ask this, I see, but I see no way the file system is going to inform you about the ultimate decision taken on this process. If you could use the ShellFileCopy Apis Windows already handles the progress bar for you in the little nice dialog shown during the copy or move.

Comment: I was thinking there might be a way to detect if a given source file location and destination file location are located on the same physical disk & partition, and if so, would this mean I could accurately anticipate the behavior. I could not easily find how to do this on msdn.  Additionally, I was hoping people might caution me if/why the approach in my comment above might not work for all file systems, so I could code accordingly.  Thank you for your suggestion about using ShellFileCopy APIs.  I will look into it but I would rather use my own library if possible.

Comment: Well, that's an easy way to get the answer to this, just not the technical proof. Speed. When a file is copied, all bytes have to be written, while actually moving a file, just rewrites the headers of the file. Therefor try making moving a 1GB file like, 5 times, and if it's instantly done, it's moving, if it takes ages, it's copy -> delete. Personally, I think `System.IO.File.Move()` moves the file, because it'd be stupid if they'd copy -> delete for performance.

Comment: Aidiakapi - (My understanding - ) File.Move will update the master file table & not copy the file if it's on the same disk/ partition.  It will do an equivalent 'copy/delete' when you are moving it onto a different partition or physical disk. I am aware of this apparent behavior, as I mention it in my question.  I need a way to figure out the behavior File.Move will choose before the operation occurs. Unless I am missing something you do not seem to be suggesting a viable way to anticipate the file.Move behavior programmatically.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always P/Invoke to [MoveFileWithProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). From a cursory reading, it looks like it'll give you more granular progress when a file is copied, rather than moved.

Alternatively, there's always [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which'll give you the Windows Explorer UI and semantics.

Comment: I may not be able to use the second suggestion as I really would prefer to use a custom UI.  I will check out both suggestions! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can detect such a thing in a normal way as you're not supposed to care. If you could test this, what would be the if and else case be as no knowledge can be extracted from this (except for the speed of the transfer).

In .net the file system is abstracted so you can just move files from one place to another without knowing what partition/filesystem/network drive you're copying from/to.

For your specific problem, why don't you always show the progressbar and have it updated at a certain interval for both cases.

Comment: I was thinking there might be a way to detect if a given source file location and destination file location are located on the same physical disk & partition, and if so, would this mean I could accurately anticipate the behaviors I describe in my post.  I desire to do this as, depending on IO load, the file transfer speed fluctuates greatly on the systems I write programs for - so I prefer giving users accurate progress indicators so they can see accurate % completed and see differences in transfer speed, when possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you can't do this.

For starters even on NTFS just looking at the drive letter for local drives isn't enough because [you can mount a drive inside an empty folder on an existing drive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/27/332704.aspx).  This means that even if the two paths have the same drive letter they could still be mounted on different disks.

To take it another step further consider external shares, possibly ones mounted on an *nix based system and exposed via Samba.  *nix symbolic links make it impossible to tell whether two paths reside on the same physical device by looking at paths alone - the only option have would be to query the remote machine "do these two paths exist on the same drive?", something which I very much doubt would be exposed.

I would just use `File.Move` and accept that you don't get progress updates.  Writing your own copy implementation strikes me as a "not a particularly good idea" anyway.

Comment: Not a good idea eh?  I disagree - It has always worked very well and allows me to customize all sorts of things I have wanted to over time =] I admit, I am a control freak.  Thanks for touching on the difficulties of doing this across different types of shares.  I can pull up hard disk IDs in Windows manually for different paths. I will still search how to harvest this information programmatically and even if this won't tell me if it is on the same partition, it will be better than nothing.  Thanks again - I will try to verify what particular file systems I can expect on our network shares.

Comment: @JHubbard80 Copying and moving files isn't normally done in user space, its best handled by the operating system.

Comment: I didn't clarify one item - I am often wrapping other built in methods that have better reporting methods than File.Copy etc. I assume those methods use OS calls - I am almost never copying blocks of bytes manually.  If by user space you mean 'by the programmer', I appreciate that it is not usually done, even by myself. However sometimes I have found it necessary and quite functional to attain a goal.  Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

While not 100% correct (sym-links make it look like things are one big partition while they may be different physical drives (from the top of my head like WHS uses extensivly), I would say for the purpose of  progress bar assuming that staying on the same partition (System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot), will probably be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about monitoring transfer speed and progress bars but for the issue of detecting if a file is being move to a diffrent drive/partition you could just compare the drive/partition letter of the destination and source file...

if you are using full paths for File.Move you could use something as simple as:

```
if(sourcePath[0]!=destinationPath[0])
    //enable transfer speed monitoring
```

if you are using relative paths you need to extract the destination/source drive/partition with a little more string path interpreting.

I'm sorry if my solution is too simple or if I'm not seeing some other problem.

Comment: The program may be using network UNC paths which can be using different physical disks but contain the same root path (and no drive letter) i.e.:  \\somename\shares\workfolder\project may be mapped to a different physical disk then \\somename\shares\workfolder\otherproject.  I can see this in Windows, but need to be able to do it programmatically (if it is deemed that this can be relied upon to anticipate the behavior)

Answer (score 0):

You can P/Invoke the GetFileInformationByHandle() function, which returns the volume serial number.  If the volume serial number is the same for both files, they are on the same volume and no copy-and-delete will be necessary.