# Windows - C#- Directory.Move

Tags: c#, windows, io

Is it guaranteed that Directory.Move only renames and not copy/delete as long as it is on the same logical drive?

Comment: I would not rely on that. there is not only NTFS out there and if you write your code on this assumption it could break anytime on other machines or disks depending on details you cannot control.

Comment: Would you rely on it if the application runs only on NTFS?!

Comment: no I would not, but below it seems like David has another idea/knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact `Directory.Move` fails if you attempt to move a directory to a different volume. If you want to perform such a move you have to do the Copy/Delete yourself. I think you can safely assume that `Directory.Move` will only ever succeed if the operation can be performed without copying files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343880/detecting-if-file-move-will-require-copy-delete-or-just-alter-location-in-th

Comment: thanks David, but are you sure about that? it kinda contradicts with the above link?!! or am I missing something?

Comment: That link appears to discuss files. Your question concerns directories. Directory.Move documentation explicitly indicates that it will fail for cross volume moves.

Comment: yeah, you are right, it is weird that the rules for directories are different from files. But I am more interested in the same volume, I want to know for sure it will never do the copy/delete operation as long as it is the same volume. If it really does it, in what scenarios? I think we can't be so sure, but like you told, may be it is safe to assume. But again, since both File.Move & Directory.Move are using the same call internally(Win32Native.MoveFile), I am a little skeptical.

Comment: Have a look at `MoveFileEx` and the `MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED`. I think the fact that you have to seek out a different API and specifically ask for the alternative behaviour suggests to me that `MoveFile` will never do its work with Copy/Delete.

Comment: I think MoveFile is doing the copy/delete in case of File.Move when moving across volumes. The question is, in what all other cases the  MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED set to true. I think we have to disassemble the MoveFile to fully understand it which I cannot. But I will go with your strong intuition until I run into troubles :).

Answer (score 1):

`Directory.Move` is an atomic operation if that's what you're getting at. It doesn't do it as 2 operations. On NTFS at least.

Comment: thanks George, but I am more interested how much time it takes. If it instant, I will not bother worrying about other processes or threads trying to read or write from/to a wrong location.