# File move - How does the OS know whether to update a master file table or copy and delete?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c, windows

After having read questions dealing with how to tell whether two files are on the same physical volume or not, and seeing that it's (almost) impossible (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7350744/939213)), I'm wondering how the OS knows whether a file move operation should update a master file table (or its equivalent) or whether to copy and delete.

Does Windows delegate that to the drives somehow?  <sub>(Or perhaps the OS *does* have information about every file, and it's just not accessible by programs? Unlikely.)</sub>

Or - Does Windows know only about certain types of drives (and copies and deletes in other cases)? In which case we could also assume the same. Which means allowing a file move without using a background thread, for example. (Because it will be near instantaneous.)

I'm trying to better understand this subject. If I'm making some basic incorrect assumption - please, correcting that in itself would be an answer.

If needed to limit the scope, let's concentrate on Windows 7 and up, and NTFS and FAT drives.

Comment: Side note: you *may* have better chance of getting answer from C/C++ part of community... C#/.Net developers generally don't need (as in "can't really  influence") to get into such internal details.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks. Edited tags accordingly.

Comment: You may add language-agnostic tag. I tried to edit the post for you but only 5 tags are allowed. If you drop any of the tag above you may choose to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the operating system knows which drive (and which partition on that drive) contains any particular local file; otherwise, how could it read the data?  (For remote files, the operating system doesn't know about the drives, but it does know which server to contact.  Moves between different servers are implemented as copy-and-delete; moves on the same server are either copy-and-delete or are delegated to that server, depending on the protocol in use.)

This information is also available to applications.  You can use the [GetFileInformationByHandle()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to obtain the serial number of the volume containing a particular file.

Comment: Thanks. Will `GetFileInformationByHandle()` work even when a drive is mounted as folder, or a folder is assigned a "drive" letter?

Comment: @ispiro: yes, it will.

Answer (score 1):

The OS does have information about every file, and it's just not as easily accessible to your program. Not in any portable way, that is.

See it this way: Those files are owned by the system. The system allocates the space, manages the volume and indexes. It's not going to copy and delete the file if it ends up in the same physical volume, as it is more efficient to move the file. It will only copy and delete if it needs to.

Comment: Not all are `owned by the system`. See [the link I now provided in the question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7350744/939213).

Answer (score 1):

In C or C++ for Windows I first try to [`MoveFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) without `MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED` set. It will fail if the file can not be moved by renaming. If rename fails I know that it may take some time and show some progress bar or the like.

There are no such rename AFAIK in .NET and that `System::IO::File::Move` of .NET does not fail if you move between different volumes.

Comment: I'm not an expert on C/C++ but the link you provided specifically says: "You can use rename to move a file from one directory **or device** to another".

Comment: @ispiro You are correct. I looked into library and discovered that I use MoveFileEx without MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED instead. Old head. Sorry, fixed my text.

Comment: Thanks for the update. +1. The phrasing "If the file is to be moved to a different volume" in the `MoveFileEx` documentation means, perhaps, that that is (usually) what will make the difference, and perhaps even, that the OS will actually not check further than that.

Answer (score 0):

***First***, regarding *Does Windows delegate that to the drives somehow*.  No.  The OS is more like a central nervous system.  It keeps track of whats going on centrally, and for its distributed assets (or devices) such as a drive. (internal or external)

***It follows that the OS***, has information about every file residing on a drive for which it has successfully enumerated.  The most relevant part of the OS with respect to file access is the ***[File System](http://www.ufsexplorer.com/und_fs.php)***.  There are ***[several types](http://www.ufsexplorer.com/und_fs.php)***.  Knowledge of the following topics will help to understand issues surrounding file access:
***1)*** ***[File attribute settings](http://www.2brightsparks.com/resources/articles/understanding-file-attributes.html)***
***2)*** ***[User Access Controls](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/user-account-control)***
***3)*** File location (***[pdf](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDgQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.cs.wpi.edu%2F~cs3013%2Fc07%2Flectures%2FSection10-File_Systems.pdf&ei=ueDPVN2cPM6zogSSoYHwAg&usg=AFQjCNFjmQ2K7Nq2jm8uja4RKHaLiQrwzw&bvm=bv.85076809,d.cGU)***) (related to User Access Controls)
***4)*** Current state of file (i.e. is the file in use currently)
***5)*** ***[Access Control Lists](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cacls.mspx?mfr=true)***

***Regarding*** *will be near instantaneous*.  This obviously is only a perception.  No matter how fast, or seemingly simultaneous, file handling via standard programming libraries can be done in such a way as to be aware of file related errors, such as:

```
ENOMEM - insufficient memory.
EMFILE - FOPEN_MAX files open already.
EINVAL - filename is NULL or contains only whitespace.
EINVAL - invalid mode.
```

(these in relation to fopen) can be used to mitigate OS/file run-time issues.    This being said, applications should always be written to comply with good programming methods to avoid bumping into OS related file access issues, thread safety included.